# make a bootable image on a removable Flash drive of Lenovo's SSD firmware update tool

Tags: gparted, usb-drive, unetbootin

How do I make a bootable Flash drive (USB type) with this file:

[Link to Lenovo SSD firmware update tool ISO image.](http://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/downloads/migr-69806)

I tried this: Use `gparted` to format to `fat32` (on an `MBR` device). This format is fast. (Edit: I also used Ubuntu's `Disks` utility to do a slow format. It makes no difference.) Then I used `unetbootin` (from the Ubuntu Software Center) to flash the device. When I boot the device it just shows a screen that has one option called "default" and it counts down from 10 and repeats in an infinite loop.

I suspect that the following command can tell you if this image file is meant for "cloning".

> isohybrid fwss31.iso

```
isohybrid: fwss31.iso: unexpected boot catalogue parameters
```

I think this error message means that the Lenovo SSD firmware update tool file is not meant for cloning. I think that if it's not meant for cloning then `unetbootin` is an appropriate tool if it would only work.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with the "isohybrid" answer and the many identical suggestions for that command that google will produce is that the file you're talking about has everything in what's called the "El Torito" boot sector of the iso 9660 image.  This is why if you just mount the file, like so

> sudo mount file.iso /cdrom

You'll see that there's nothing there, no space available, and all the space used. This magic is made possible by the mysterious El Torito Boot sector.

So how do you get that?

We'll use yet another tool, in debian it's [genisoimage](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/genisoimage). The program you need in this package is called `geteltorito`.

Now do something like this:

```
$ geteltorito XXX.iso > XXX.finally_working_gahhhhhh.img
$ sudo dd if=XXX.finally_working_gahhhhhh.img of=/dev/sdb
```

And finally, there we go. We can now move on with our lives. Yay!

Note: Thanks to [this blog](https://johnleach.co.uk/words/2014/03/01/booting-thinkpad-firmware-updater-from-a-usb-key/) which finally gave me the secret here.

Comment: See also this Arch Wiki entry: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_6)#Manual_(El_Torito)

Comment: I got a 28KB img file from a 2.4GB iso. Not working on Ubuntu 22.04. All I wanted to do to add a 32bit EFI file to the Linux Mint installer, but looks like it is impossible in 2022. I'll check a different OS, this version of Ubuntu sucks.

Answer (score 0):

`unetbootin` & USB disk creator could be used only with live Linux images.

- You may use `dd`, but it is dangerous. Check very well the target disk, use `fdisk -l` or `gnome-disks`.

  ```
  sudo dd if=fwss31.iso of=/dev/sdX
  ```
- Another option (GUI) is Rosa ISO USB Image Writer from [Parrot distribution  site](https://www.parrotsec.org/download.fx)

Comment: From Wikipedia: "UNetbootin (Universal Netboot Installer) is a cross-platform utility that can create live USB systems and can load a variety of system utilities or install various Linux distributions and other operating systems without a CD." By that description a utility such as the Lenovo Flash update tool which is an ISO image is not excluded.

Comment: @H2ONaCl, I had seen some cases where `unetbootin` created usb couldn't boot, for Parrot distribution image. I agree to they list here some non-linux images https://unetbootin.github.io/ . Better, to test it and see.